# How to print a dynamic table with 4 columns from PHP array and to add empty <td> to complete the table row

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have the following php array and I am trying to print a table with 4 columns. All is OK until the array has 4, 8, 12 and etc. keys /values but when array has length that can not be divided by 4 becomes the problem. Here is the sample array:

```
$newarray =array(
"make"=> "Ford" ,
"model"=> "S-MAX" ,
"model_year"=> "2009" ,
"made"=>  "2010-01-01" ,
"manufacturer"=>  "Ford Werke AG" ,
"manufacturer_address"=>  "Koeln-Niehl, Germany" ,
"body"=> "Sedan/Saloon" ,
"engine_power_kw"=> "142" ,
"engine_displacement_ccm"=> "2000" ,
"engine_full"=> "2.0L Duratorq-TDCi (143PS) - DW" 
);
```

and the code that prints the table:

```
$rama_result.='<table class="table w100 customtable">';
$i=1;
foreach($newarray as $key=>$value){
$rama_result1.= '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
$rama_result2.= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';

if($i % 4 == 0){
    $rama_result.='</tr><tr>'.$rama_result1.'</tr><tr>'.$rama_result2.'</tr><tr>';
    $rama_result1 = '';$rama_result2 = '';
    }
$i++;
}
    $rama_result.='</tr></table>';
```

Can you please help and show me the way to print the missing 2  in the last row so the code to work correct. Thank you for your help

The code above prints this table

```
<table class="table w100 customtable"><tbody>
<tr><th>make</th><th>model</th><th>model_year</th><th>made</th></tr>
<tr><td>Ford</td><td>S-MAX</td><td>2009</td><td>2010-01-01</td></tr><tr></tr>
<tr><th>manufacturer</th><th>manufacturer_address</th><th>body</th><th>engine_power_kw</th></tr>
<tr><td>Ford Werke AG</td><td>Koeln-Niehl, Germany</td><td>Sedan/Saloon</td>    <td>142</td></tr>
<tr></tr></tbody></table>
```

```html
<table class="table w100 customtable"><tbody>
<tr><th>make</th><th>model</th><th>model_year</th><th>made</th></tr>
<tr><td>Ford</td><td>S-MAX</td><td>2009</td><td>2010-01-01</td></tr><tr></tr>
<tr><th>manufacturer</th><th>manufacturer_address</th><th>body</th><th>engine_power_kw</th></tr>
<tr><td>Ford Werke AG</td><td>Koeln-Niehl, Germany</td><td>Sedan/Saloon</td>    <td>142</td></tr>
<tr></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: the last row has only 2 td's but above 4 td's

Comment: I noticed. Thanks.

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it? Otherwise, please consider marking the answer which best solved your problem accepted.

Comment: Yes Nick, I used yours and marked it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just extend the array to have a multiple of 4 elements before you start:

```
for ($c = count($newarray); $c % 4 != 0; $c++) {
    $newarray[str_repeat("\n", $c % 4)] = '';
}
$rama_result.='<table class="table w100 customtable">';
$i=1;
// ...
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JtKDu)

Comment: The problem with this is when you get to the new elements it's added - you end up with `<th>0</th><th>1</th>`

Comment: @NigelRen you're right... I hadn't looked closely enough at the output

Comment: #Nick, your code seems to print the table correct, but for some reason the empty th has value 0, 1 and etc.. Where is this being generated? I can see $newarray[] = ''; but prints number..

Comment: @Europeuser it's because PHP automatically assigns a numeric index to new array elements if an index is not specified. I've modified the code to use a repeated newline instead (which don't display), you could equally use a space character or similar.

Comment: yes yes, I figured it out but after I posted the comment, Thank you,

Comment: Also as pointed out - there will be an extra row at the end (see original output)

Comment: #Nick, this is a working solution, Thank you for your help.! #Nigel Thank you for your efforts, but I could not succeed to make your code working..

Comment: Nick latest version of your code not working, returns error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: No worries. Btw make sure you look at @Andreas answer it's nice and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping each value use array_chunk to split the array then implode the headers and values.

```
$arr = array_chunk($newarray, 4, true);
echo "<table>\n";
foreach($arr as $sub){
    echo "<tr><th>" . implode("</th><th>", array_keys($sub)) . implode("</th><th>", array_slice([" ", " ", " "],0 , 4-count($sub)))  . "</th></tr>\n";
    echo "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $sub) . implode("</td><td>", array_slice([" ", " ", " "],0 , 5-count($sub))) ."</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Output:

```
<table>
<tr><th>make</th><th>model</th><th>model_year</th><th>made</th></tr>
<tr><td>Ford</td><td>S-MAX</td><td>2009</td><td>2010-01-01 </td></tr>
<tr><th>manufacturer</th><th>manufacturer_address</th><th>body</th><th>engine_power_kw</th></tr>
<tr><td>Ford Werke AG</td><td>Koeln-Niehl, Germany</td><td>Sedan/Saloon</td><td>142 </td></tr>
<tr><th>engine_displacement_ccm</th><th>engine_full </th><th> </th></tr>
<tr><td>2000</td><td>2.0L Duratorq-TDCi (143PS) - DW </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
</table>
```

https://3v4l.org/TrCnM

Edited to include the empty cells.

Comment: I like the use of `array_chunk` and `implode` but this doesn't resolve OPs problem with not having arrays which don't have a number of elements which is a multiple of 4.

Comment: It does. It prints all items as requested (?). See engine displacement @Nick

Comment: But it doesn't print blank entries to fill the last row out to 4 elements.

Comment: I do not see that as a requirement from OP. But sure that's an easy fix.

Comment: "when array has length that can not be divided by 4 becomes the problem" ... "please help and show me the way to print the missing 2 in the last row"

Comment: Yes the missing two is engine displacement and engine full. There is no mention of empty values in the question.

Comment: The last row in your table only has two elements. OP needs it to have 4 to make it the same width as the prior rows.

Comment: @Nick again it doesn't say so in the question! Read it again and look what OP means with missing items.

Comment: OP does say it in the first comment. Sure it could be clearer. Anyway your code looks good now.

Comment: #Andreas, sorry for the late evaluation of your answer! Its working well and prints the desired table correct! Thank you for your time and help !

Answer (score 1):

After the loop, you could check that there is something still in `$rama_result1` - which would mean there is data left to be added into the table.  This code pads the existing content with enough empty cells to make it up to the 4 columns (you can tweak the content if desired in the `str_repeat()` calls).

```
if ( $rama_result1 != '' )  {
    $i--;
    $rama_result1 .= str_repeat("<th />", 4-($i%4));
    $rama_result2 .= str_repeat("<td />", 4-($i%4));
    $rama_result.='<tr>'.$rama_result1.'</tr><tr>'.$rama_result2.'</tr>';
}
```

Also (as Nick pointed out) there are extra `<tr>` tags in various places.  I've updated a few other parts of the code to try and tidy up the generated HTML...

```
$i=1;
foreach($newarray as $key=>$value){
    $rama_result1.= '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
    $rama_result2.= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';

    if($i % 4 == 0){
        $rama_result.='<tr>'.$rama_result1.'</tr><tr>'.$rama_result2.'</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
        $rama_result1 = '';
        $rama_result2 = '';
    }
    $i++;
}
if ( $rama_result1 != '' )  {
    $i--;
    echo ($i%4).PHP_EOL;

    $rama_result1 .= str_repeat("<th />", 4-($i%4));
    $rama_result2 .= str_repeat("<td />", 4-($i%4));
    $rama_result.='<tr>'.$rama_result1.'</tr><tr>'.$rama_result2.'</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
}
$rama_result.='</table>';
```

Comment: #Nigel, where this code should be placed within my code?

Comment: Add it after the close `}` for the loop and before `$rama_result.='</tr></table>';`

Comment: I think this will repeat too many times. What you want is `$i%4 == 0 => 0; 1 => 3; 2 => 2; 3 => 1`

Comment: Actually it's generating an empty `<tr>`, you need to remove the `'</tr><tr>'` from the end of the last line.

Comment: #Nigel still printing extra th td's and table start looking like pyramid..

Comment: #Nigel Thank you for your efforts, but I could not succeed to make your code working..